# Rouché's Theorem: How many roots does $\lambda-z=\frac{1}{3}e^{z^2}$ have in the strip Re$(z)\in [-1,1]$?

Tags: complex-analysis, roots, rouches-theorem

I'm studying for my complex analysis qual, and I've found a problem that I haven't seen solved here yet:

Take $\lambda$ to be purely imaginary. Prove that $z-\lambda=\frac{1}{3}e^{z^2}$ has exactly one solution in the strip
$S:=\{x+iy:x\in [-1,1]\}$ .

I've tried showing that the roots are all in the disk $|\lambda-z|=\frac{1}{3}|e^{z^2}|=\frac{1}{3}e^{x^2-y^2}\leq \frac
{1}{3}e$, but after this, I have that on the circle $|\lambda-z|=\frac{1}{3}e$, $|\lambda-z|\geq \frac{1}{3}e^{z^2}$, where equality holds when the real part of $z$ is $\pm 1$ and the imaginary part is $0$. If I'm remembering correctly, the conditions for Rouché's Theorem require *strict* inequality.

How should I proceed?

Answer (score 1):

On the circle
$|\lambda-z|=\frac{1}{3}e\;$we have
\begin{align*}
&
|\lambda-z| < 1
\\[4pt]
\implies\;\;&
|\text{Re}(\lambda-z)| < 1
\\[4pt]
\implies\;\;&
|\text{Re}(\lambda)-\text{Re}(z)| < 1
\\[4pt]
\implies\;\;&
|-\text{Re}(z)| < 1
\\[4pt]
\implies\;\;&
|\text{Re}(z)| < 1
\\[4pt]
\end{align*}
so we can't have $\text{Re}(z)=\pm 1$.